# Postfix: change recipient_delimiter with virtual_mailboxes

Tags: postgresql, postfix, mail-server, dovecot

I have an email setup using Postfix, Dovecot, PostgreSQL. I am trying to change the recipient_delimiter to be **-** (dash) instead of **+** (plus) but the address are being rejected. In order to get the **+** working for my setup I needed to add the following to my postfix config:

```
#/etc/postfix/master.cf
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -a ${recipient} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
```

However, once I change the config to use **-** (dash) as my recipient_delimiiter, the server no longer accepts any addresses with `-blah` suffixes.

Is there something I need to configure within Dovecot to ignore anything after a dash or is there something else that needs to be done in postfix so that it only passes the text before the dash to dovecot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being as simple as also adding `recipient_delimiter = -` to the /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf